# mysql query for searching

Tags: mysql, sql, web

I am developing a web-interface for generate reports, all code is complete and done.

But I don't know how can I write mysql query for User interface.

Example:

My table name is "product".

Above mention table contain 4 column.

1. Search
2. Category
3. Province
4. City

**My task is user provide one or more parameter and result is display**
SIMPLE

But I don't know how can I handle situation if user provide less than four parameter(0 , 1 , 2 , 3)

Please find me query:

Example:
1. If user only type in search field and does not type any thing in category, province and city.
2. if user type only search and province, but do not provide category or city.

I hope that you have given me good and positive reply soon.

Click on this link my web user interface is here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUUaa.png
![User Interface][1]

Comment: How about checking against the `$_POST` array for the supplied search filters and build the `WHERE` query from thereon? Example `$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WEHRE 1"; $sql .= (isset($_POST['filter_category']) && $_POST['filter_category']) ? " AND category = ?" : '';` and so on and so on....

Comment: Dear TechHouse,

Thank you!

Please send me full query,

My six sense is continuslly blinking , you give me right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE 1";
$params = array();

foreach ($_POST['filters'] as $filter_key => $filter_value) {
$sql .= " AND $filter_key = ? ";
$params[] = $filter_value;
}

$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($query->execute($params)) {
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($results);
}
else {
echo $query->errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: Dear Tech House, Please define this query for how can I utilize this query in my scenario.

Comment: What do you mean? It's all there! Just use it with PHP's PDO. :)